# ubuntu user& ssh login permission denied messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I use ubuntu 14.04 to set up my apps enviroment. install rbenv - ruby +rails, nginx + passenger, all done.

but when I want to create a depoly user
something wrong! when I logout and login with john(I login successfully), I got following messages, does I change some setting? and I just login, not create folder, so this messages is so confusing, I have no authority now(like rails -v, ruby -v...etc.), 
but I still can use sudo to do something like **sudo visudo**

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-48-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

  System information as of Sun Aug  2 17:23:20 CST 2015

  System load:  0.0               Processes:           
  Usage of /:   9.3% of 19.55GB   Users logged in:     1
  Memory usage: 2%                IP address for eth0: 
  Swap usage:   0%

  Graph this data and manage this system at:
    https://landscape.canonical.com/

  Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:
    http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud


*** System restart required ***
Last login: Sun Aug  2 17:23:21 2015 from ip.dynamic.hinet.net
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/rbenv/shims’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/rbenv/versions’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/rbenv/shims’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/rbenv/versions’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/rbenv/shims’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/rbenv/versions’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/rbenv/shims’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/rbenv/versions’: Permission denied
```

and here is my user setting:

```
# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
john    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rbenv install is broken. Uninstall it completely:

```
rm -rf `rbenv root`
```

Then reinstall rbenv using *local* installation (use deployer user for it), look rbenv site for instructions:

https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#installation

Your resulting folder should be /home/deployer/.rbenv instead of /usr/local/rbenv.